# How to check if the address the pointer points to is 0x0?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer where I "manually" set the address it points to:

```
pPlayerPool = reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(someAddress+PLAYER_POOL_POINTER_OFFSET);
```

When the game didn't start yet, `pPlayerPool` points to 0x0, that's what it says in my memory searching tool. I tried to check it with

```
if(*pPlayerPool)
```

or

```
if(*pPlayerPool != 0)
```

or

```
if(*pPlayerPool != NULL)
```

My program always crashed, when it was 0x0.

And then I have another small question: As I know `*` gives me the value of the pointer and `&` the address of the pointer itself. But what does that value mean that I get without any of these characters?

Comment: First of all, what is `someAddress` pointing at? Another executable? Dynamically allocated or fixed data?

Comment: `someAddress` is not a pointer. It just holds an address.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's just holds an address. But the point of using reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(..) is to MAKE it into a pointer. So let's rephrase it: What is at that address? Is there ANYTHING there at the time when you want to check for NULL?

Comment: @MazzMan Pointers are just variables that hold addresses.  We would need to know what you are trying to point to.  If `someAddress` isn't a known, pointed to address, your program is probably crashing because you are trying to access memory that your program **is not allowed to access**.  This causes the operating system to kill your program, aka segfault.

Answer (score 5):

That is because you are trying to **dereference a null pointer**. Don't dereference it just check the value of it.

```
if(pPlayerPool)

if(pPlayerPool != 0)
```

---

When you do this

```
*pPlayerPool != 0
```

you are testing if **what is pointed** to by `pPlayerPool` is zero. Not that `pPlayerPool` is sero.

Comment: That will test if `someAddress+PLAYER_POOL_POINTER_OFFSET` is 0. Assuming that `PLAYER_POOL_POINTER_OFFSET` isn't the negative value of `someAddress`, that will not work. I don't see why anyone is upvoting this answer, as it's not actually answering what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @MatsPetersson they are still correct in pointing out a problem with OPs code, though it doesn't solve the original problem they are working towards. Trying to deference a NULL pointer will throw an access violation.

Comment: @MazzMan I think I might not be clear on your problem. wht is causing your crash is what is stated in the answer. what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Named I need to check if `pPlayerPointer` points to the address 0x0 so I can avoid to use the variable and crashing the program.

Comment: @Cyber: But the address dereferenced isn't NULL! It is `someAddress + PLAYER_POOL_POINTER_OFFSET` - and unless these completely match each other with opposite sign (or are both zero), it's always going to be non-zero. Sadly, there is no easy way to easily determine if a pointer is valid or not (if it's not NULL). Only way is to try to access the memory and see if it works.

Comment: @MazzMan Then use exactly what I wrote in the answer i.e. don't  dereference the pointer with '*' before checking it is zero or null as in the answer..

Comment: Are you sure that `someAddress` isn't what is zero? And then adding `PLAYER_POOL_POINTER_OFFSET` makes it non-zero? It seems very unlikely that the sum would be zero for this...

Comment: @MatsPetersson If i am not mistaken I think he mixed up the question. The code you are referring to might be here just for "demonstration". He says "When the game didn't start yet, pPlayerPool points to 0x0". and I think that is what he is trying to check.

Comment: So, is pPlayerPool NULL or POINTING at NULL?

Comment: I want to check if pPlayerPool points to the ADDRESS 0x0. So I tried to do `*pPlayerPool != NULL` because `*pPlayerPool` gives me the address it is pointing to.

Comment: @MazzMan I understand your problem. But the issue is at that point in the code `pPlayerPool` is 0x0 (NULL) itself. i.e It is not pointing to anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `*pointerName`, you are retrieving the value that is being pointed to.
`&someValue` gives you a pointer *to the address of* `someValue`.  For example:

```
int *pointer;
int value;

value = 4;
pointer = &value;
// pointer now points to the address of value.
// *pointer will now give you a value of 4
```

If you use `&pointerName`, you are getting a pointer to the address of your pointer.  That is, the result is a pointer to a pointer.

```
int **pointerToPointer;
pointerToPointer = &pointer;
// now if you dereference pointerToPointer twice, you will get 4
// if you dereference it once, you will have the address of value
```

If you use a pointer without either of those operators, it is just the number of the address that is being pointed at.

For your if statements, you are using `*pPlayerPool`.  This means you are trying to access the value at the location pointed to, which you have already said is 0x0.  It is an error to access 0x0, and the operating system will kill your program if you try.  Instead, just use `pPlayerPool`:

```
if(pPlayerPool)
// or
if(pPlayerPool != 0)
```

Furthermore, why are you setting a pointer manually?  That's very dangerous and can (read: **will**) lead to more errors later.  If you are trying to collect a number of values in one place, use a class or a struct, as then the compiler can calculate data offsets for you.

Comment: But the problem is that even if `*pPlayerPool` is 0x0, `pPlayerPointer` is not.

Comment: @MazzMan Well, yes.  There is not necessarily any relationship between the value of a pointer and the value it points to.  But you need to check the correct thing.  Checking `*pPlayerPool` doesn't mean much.  If you set the pointer manually your problem may be that you are pointing outside of memory that your program owns, in which case the operating system will terminate your program.

Answer (score 0):

If `*pPlayerPool` is NULL, then you should be able to do:

```
if (*pPlayerPool)
```

(or any number of variants on that theme).

However, it sounds like this goes wrong. I expect that is because you are trying to manipulate memory in another process that you are either injecting a DLL into or "debugging" with the debug interface, where that other process is not "ready" or "started". In which case you won't be able to check that address at all, because its memory is simply not there. The address itself is not "valid".

You will either need to find a different way to determine in the game has started, or use Windows Strucuted Exception handling, e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The example in the link shows how to "catch" a divide by zero, but you can use the same thing to check if a memory access is valid, etc. [`GetExceptionCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will give you a `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` if you have a memory access violation.

Comment: If `pPlayerPool` is type `int *` then `*pPlayerPool` is type `int`.  Whether or not that integer being pointed to happens to be equal to 0 (ie NULL) shouldn't cause the program to crash unless it is used in some other calculation.  What would cause the program to crash would be if `pPlayerPool` pointed to a memory location not owned by the program.

Comment: Yes, exactly - it is a "cheat engine for a game" (by the looks of things), so it's by definition trying to make a pointer to something that isn't in it's own range of "known variables". It may of course be that the OP is completely confused and trying to use an address that belongs in another process, without actually having access to that process at all - in which case it will NEVER work.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it does seem like he might be trying to do that.  Obviously with virtual memory and all, even if the address he chose was owned by his program, he would still not get the value as the other program saw it.